# Angular 5 HashLocation Strategy Not Navigating

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, aspnetboilerplate, angular-router

I have been trying to implement `HashLocationStrategy` after deploying my Angular 5 Application to IIS. In my Angular application, there are 3 modules: `RootModule` and 2 lazy-loaded modules (`AccountModule`, and `AppModule`).

After authenticating in the `AccountModule`'s component, the application should *navigate to the main component in the `AppModule`*. But it does not navigate like it should after clicking "login" button. Only when I manually refresh, it will direct me to the app module.

Do I need to put any additional configurations or imports in the child module or is just configuring the root module sufficient? Or is there anything wrong with my configurations?

Here's my code:

**Root routing module:**

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/app/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'account',
        loadChildren: 'account/account.module#AccountModule', //Lazy load account module
        data: { preload: true }
    },
    {
        path: 'app',
        loadChildren: 'app/app.module#AppModule', //Lazy load account module
        data: { preload: true }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
        onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', useHash: true, enableTracing: true
    })],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    providers: []
})
```

**Root Module:**

```ts
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // ...,
        RootRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        RootComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        // ...,
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
    ],
    bootstrap: [RootComponent]
})

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild([
            {
                path: '',
                component: AccountComponent,
                children: [
                    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
                    { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
                ]
            }
        ])
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
```

### Steps

When I enter in the user credentials and click login, it doesn't navigate to `#/app/home`, it just stays where it is now. But it is already authenticated.
[image]

I have to manually type in the root url, in the address bar. 
[image]

Only then, I am directed to `#/app/home`

[image]

#### Tracing Navigation

This is captured in the console log after I clicked on the login button.

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart(id: 3, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart {id: 3, url: "/"}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized(id: 3, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') }  }  } )
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized {id: 3, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/app/home", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart(id: 3, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') }  }  } )
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart {id: 3, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart(path: 'app')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart(path: 'app')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart(path: 'home')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 3, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') }  }  } , shouldActivate: false)
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd {id: 3, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: false}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: NavigationCancel
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationCancel(id: 3, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationCancel {id: 3, url: "/", reason: ""}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart(id: 4, url: '/account/login')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart {id: 4, url: "/account/login"}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized(id: 4, url: '/account/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/account/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'account', path:'account') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') }  }  } )
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized {id: 4, url: "/account/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/account/login", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart(id: 4, url: '/account/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/account/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'account', path:'account') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') }  }  } )
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart {id: 4, url: "/account/login", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 4, url: '/account/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/account/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'account', path:'account') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') }  }  } , shouldActivate: true)
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd {id: 4, url: "/account/login", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd(path: 'login')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd(path: 'account')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd(path: 'account')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: NavigationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationEnd(id: 4, url: '/account/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/account/login')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationEnd {id: 4, url: "/account/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/account/login"}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart(id: 5, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart {id: 5, url: "/"}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized(id: 5, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') }  }  } )
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized {id: 5, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: "/app/home", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart(id: 5, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') }  }  } )
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart {id: 5, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart(path: 'app')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart(path: 'app')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationStart
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart(path: 'home')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationStart {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 5, url: '/', urlAfterRedirects: '/app/home', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'app', path:'app') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'home', path:'home') }  }  } , shouldActivate: false)
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd {id: 5, url: "/", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: false}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: NavigationCancel
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationCancel(id: 5, url: '/')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationCancel {id: 5, url: "/", reason: ""}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart(id: 6, url: '/account/login')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationStart {id: 6, url: "/account/login"}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: RoutesRecognized
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized(id: 6, url: '/account/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/account/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'account', path:'account') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') }  }  } )
platform-browser.js:367 RoutesRecognized {id: 6, url: "/account/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/account/login", state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckStart
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart(id: 6, url: '/account/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/account/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'account', path:'account') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') }  }  } )
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckStart {id: 6, url: "/account/login", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: GuardsCheckEnd
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd(id: 6, url: '/account/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/account/login', state: Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'account', path:'account') { Route(url:'', path:'') { Route(url:'login', path:'login') }  }  } , shouldActivate: true)
platform-browser.js:367 GuardsCheckEnd {id: 6, url: "/account/login", urlAfterRedirects: UrlTree, state: RouterStateSnapshot, shouldActivate: true}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd(path: 'login')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd(path: 'account')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd(path: 'account')
platform-browser.js:367 ActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: ChildActivationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd(path: '')
platform-browser.js:367 ChildActivationEnd {snapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot}
platform-browser.js:380 Router Event: NavigationEnd
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationEnd(id: 6, url: '/account/login', urlAfterRedirects: '/account/login')
platform-browser.js:367 NavigationEnd {id: 6, url: "/account/login", urlAfterRedirects: "/account/login"}
```

Comment: Screenshots? Errors? Stackblitz demo? Could you show us any one of these?

Comment: @Edric Sure, I'm working on it

Comment: @Edric Done adding screenshots and captions!

Comment: do you have problem when you run on IIS Express (while you are using Visual Studio). I just tried with the latest version. No problems navigating after successful login!

Comment: try with different browser (if you are using IE)